# How to split a huge video into smaller files automatically in windows?

Tags: video-editor, video-recording

is there an app that I can use windows that can take a video and divide the file to N number of files? Like for a 1 hour video, I'd like to create 6 videos or 12 then it will automatically determine where to split it.

I discovered this amazing site that does it: https://split-video.com/, but it's just taking too much time and I can probably take advantage of my computer that has good memory and gpu.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/)? It has several options how to split video on equal parts.

Comment: Can you explain how?  An example of how to install on windows, and a line of ffmpeg code would be useful

Comment: Just download and unpack the ffmpeg package, go to bin directory and run the command:
  
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:10:00 -c copy output1.mp4
  
(-i  input file
-ss start time in seconds or in hh:mm:ss
-to end time in seconds or in hh:mm:ss
-c codec to use)
  
kudos: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/508008

Comment: nah, I haven't tried to use it in windows. I might just be too lazy to install it on windows. tried it before in linux and it's flawless. installation might be not as smooth in windows but I'll give it a shot